# Angular use different layouts for different routes

Tags: angular

I am having a problem with using different layouts in my angular application. Currently I have defined the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent, outlet: 'default' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginRegisterComponent, outlet: 'default' },
      { path: 'register', component: LoginRegisterComponent, outlet: 'default' },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'companies',
    component: CmsLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CompanyIndexComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
      { path: ':id', component: CompanyViewComponent, outlet: 'cms' },
    ]
  },
];
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to have a default layout which is the `DefaultLayoutComponent`

Inside this component I have defined a some styling and a:

```
<router-outlet name="default"></router-outlet>
```

I have done the same for the CmsLayoutComponent with a:

```
<router-outlet name="cms"></router-outlet>
```

The landing page gets loaded succesfully, but when I try to navigate to /login for instance, I get redirected back to the root route, with the CmsLayoutComponent, but without any other component loaded in the router outlet. My console prints:

```
core.mjs:8416 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use named outlets in your case. Named outlets are needed when you have *multiple outlets on the same page*. It could be a split layout. In your case each component is present on the page and the other one is not. Therefore you need to use default routing with no names.

**Update with breakdown**

You have routes and sub-routes. Whenever a sub-route is matched its parent is mounted. It contains `router-outlet` and therefore Angular knows where to mount the matched route. If you didn't put `router-outlet` in the parent component (e.g. CmsLayoutComponent) Angular would not be able to mount a page, because there is no outlet.

With named route-outlets it's when you have a following routing structure

- /route

  - /route-A, outletA
  - /route-B, outletB

Your component on the `/route` can have a following markup

```
<router-outlet name="outletA" />
<router-outlet name="outletB" />
```

Then you would be able to mount both `/route-A` and `/route-B` at the same time.

The logic described previously still applies. You need to have a direct parent with all outlets specified.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that angular would pick automatically the correct router outlet! Thanks for your help, this helps me a lot! Still a question about my routing setup, how should I define the routes if some routes use the default layout and some the CMS layout?

Comment: It's not Angular picking the correct outlet. It's that you have only one outlet on the page in a single time. Whichever sub-route is matched - component is mounted and it has `router-outlet`. And Angular attaches to it. Inactive pages are not present in DOM

Answer (score 0):

So for those who are wondering, this is the final solution based on @Sergey's Response.

In **app-routing.module.ts** define the following routes with no outlet names:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginRegisterComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: LoginRegisterComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'companies',
    component: CmsLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CompanyIndexComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: CompanyViewComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

And in both `DefaultLayoutComponent` and `CmsLayoutComponent` use the `router-outlet` tag with no name attribute:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```